# How can I determine the cause for unknown file deletion

Tags: windows, windows-8, ssd, file-management

Ok, a very strange thing happened to me this morning. I was using my PC, and a lot of my applications started to hang for some reason. Turns out that a lot of my files (~7gb worth) have disappeared all of a sudden. This includes files in my desktop, C:, some in program files, documents etc, there's recognizable no pattern for the location of file deletion.  Off the top of my head, I can think of four avenues on which this could've happened:

1. One of my running applications executed file delete command
2. SSD Went bad and it somehow started to overwrite my existing files when
   it was performing file IO.
3. A malware or virus
4. Someone somehow accessed my computer remotely with backdoor of sorts and performed
   delete

I have backups, so there's no real damage done but I still want to determine the exact cause for this behavior. So far, I have tried the following:

1. Checked eventvwr for system/windows logs and see if there were any noticeable errors/warnings, particularly with disk drive. I couldn't find any.
2. Ran CrystalDiskInfo to see if there were any errors with SSD. None could be found.
3. Performed threat scan with MalwareBytes. No threat found.
4. Verified that windows firewall was up and running.
5. Ran chkdsk. Again, no errors found.

I'm beginning to think one of my running applications actually performed delete command on C:\ without me knowing (I had some applications performing IO at the time).

**What steps can I take to locate the exact cause for file erasure?** Particularly, is there any log tracking which application issued delete command?

Comment: I'd check the health status of your hdd (SMART stats), and of your filesystem (chkdsk). There is not likely any way to tell for sure, unless you find health issues with your disk or filesystem.

Comment: @FrankThomas Yeah.. I've done both.. CrystalDiskInfo checks for health status from SMART and ran chkdsk.. again no errors found

Comment: Maybe moved elsewhere with file explorer `drag&drop` feature by accident?